# Python gmail-smtp script works from win\3.6, not linux\3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail

The following script works perfectly fine from my Win 10 box using Python 3.6:

```
import smtplib,subprocess

def send_email(user, pwd, recipient, subject, body):


    FROM = user
    TO = recipient if isinstance(recipient, list) else [recipient]
    SUBJECT = subject
    TEXT = body

    # Prepare actual message
    message = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
    """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
        server.close()
        print ('successfully sent the mail')
    except Exception as e:
                            print(e)
                            print ("failed to send mail")

send_email("user@gmail.com", "pass", "dst@email.com", "some subject", "some body")
```

However, it fails with a

> "Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again"

when I try to run it from a Ubuntu 16.04 box and Python 3.5.2.
I should mention that "allow unsecure apps" is enabled on my gmail account (didnt work from the Win box without it).

Comment: And what happened when you "[logged] in via your web browser and [tried] again"?

Comment: Same thing. No change.